# Android How to deserialize xml containing list of objects using Simple api

Tags: android, xml

need to deserialize an xml response to an object, using simple api. When I deserialize an object, , I get an exception: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Transducer' does not have a match in class java.lang.Object at line 1

would appreciate a clue on what I am doing wrong or a working example for deserializing an inline list with complex objects.

Thanks.

Attached is a simplified example of my objects:

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Profile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Transducers>
    <Transducer Value="0" Name="nDate" Unit="" ChineseName="时间" IsVisibility="true" Formatter="yyyyMMddHHmm" MessageLength="12" />
    <Transducer Value="0" Name="EnvirTemp" Unit="℃" ChineseName="环温" IsVisibility="true" Formatter="0.0" MessageLength="4" />
    <Transducer Value="0" Name="EnvirHumid" Unit="%RH" ChineseName="环湿" IsVisibility="true" Formatter="0.0" MessageLength="4" />
  </Transducers>
  <MMX>
    <Transducers>
      <Transducer Value="0" Name="aa" Unit="" ChineseName="a" IsVisibility="true" Formatter="0.0" MessageLength="4" />
      <Transducer Value="0" Name="bb" Unit="" ChineseName="a" IsVisibility="true" Formatter="0.0" MessageLength="4" />
    </Transducers>
  </MMX>
</Profile>
```

my objects:

```
@Root
public class Profile {

    @ElementList(entry="Transducer")
    public List<Transducer> Transducers;

    @ElementList
    public List<List<Transducer>> MMX;
}


@Element
public class Transducer {
    @Attribute
    public double Value;

    @Attribute
    public String Name;

    @Attribute
    public String Unit;

    @Attribute
    public String ChineseName;

    @Attribute
    public boolean IsVisibility;

    @Attribute
    public String Formatter;

    @Attribute
    public String MessageLength;
}
```

I had add private and  setter and getter for each property and I had serialized by write

```
<profile>
   <CreateDate>2015-3-25</CreateDate>
   <Id>1</Id>
   <Name>pc4</Name>
   <RecorderId>00000</RecorderId>
   <Transducers class="java.util.ArrayList">
      <Transducer ChineseName="温度" Formatter="0.0" Unit="C" MessageLength="4" Name="Temperature1" IsVisibility="true" Value="0.0"/>
      <Transducer ChineseName="温度2" Formatter="0.0" Unit="C" MessageLength="4" Name="Temperature2" IsVisibility="true" Value="0.0"/>
   </Transducers>
</profile>
```

I deseriized from my.xml that I get exception like

org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Transducer' does not have a match in class java.lang.Object at line 1

Comment: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Transducer' does not have a match in class java.lang.Object at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make your properties private and create getter and setter for each of them?

Comment: No,I used smple api in android

Comment: I had make my properties private and create getter for each item but I still get an exception: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Transducer' does not have a match in class java.lang.Object at line 1

Comment: try to put @ElementList(name="etudes") and to put 
@Root(name="Transducer")